# Timeline view with JQuery Fullcalendar plugin

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to do a timeline view with the JQuery FullCalendar plugin (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)?  I'm looking to do something like this: http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_timeline.shtml

I like the look of fullcalendar over dhtmlx though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a common issue on google code called but it is labeled "resource view" instead of timeline... here is the link ["resource view"](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=150&q=resource&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars). Maybe it will geve you a place to start... let me know if it helps